# JSON Encoding Error While Loading String from a File

Tags: python, json, encoding, decode, python-unicode

After opening and before loading a json file on phython, the code end up getting a string filled with unicode blocks between every character. Its seems to be a encoding problem, any easy way to solve this problem?

```
import json
import io

# read file
with open('BOVA111618484700 (1).json', 'r',encoding="ASCII") as myfile:
data=myfile.read()

print(data)
# parse file
obj = json.loads(data)
```

print(data) shows:

```
[�
�{�
�"�d�a�t�a�h�o�r�a�"�:� �"�2�0�2�1�.�0�4�.�1�5� �1�1�:�0�5�:�0�0�"�,�
�"�m�i�l�i�s�e�c�o�n�d�s�"�:� �"�1�6�1�8�4�8�4�7�0�0�2�3�4�"�,�
�"�b�i�d�"�:� �"�1�1�6�.�3�2�"�,�
�"�a�s�k�"�:� �"�1�1�6�.�3�6�"�,�
�"�l�a�s�t�"�:� �"�1�1�6�.�3�2�"�,�
�"�v�o�l�u�m�e�"�:� �"�1�"�,�
�"�f�l�a�g�s�"�:� �"�2�"�
�}�,�                  #json string continues...
```

when it should show:

```
[
{
"datahora": "2021.04.15 11:05:00",
"miliseconds": "1618484700234",
"bid": "116.32",
"ask": "116.36",
"last": "116.32",
"volume": "1",
"flags": "2"
},      #json string continues...
```

After the print, the json.load function returns this error:
`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: The file may use UTF-16 encoding, not ASCII.

Comment: You're telling Python to read the file as if it has been "ASCII" encoded, but it clearly isn't. Check what the encoding of the file really is and read it accordingly. If it's UTF-8, you don't need to specify that, as that's the default. Why were you specifying the encoding?

Comment: Tks @tevemadar, but after changing to `open('BOVA111618484700 (1).json', 'r',encoding="UTF-16")` the result was `UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM`

Comment: Tks @Grismar! I only specified after the first decode error. Sadly changing to UTF-8 or default returns the same error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Grismar and @tevemadar the encode of the file was actually "UTF-16 LE" assigning this to the open function solve everything!

```
import json
import io

# read file
with open('BOVA111618484700 (1).json', 'r',encoding="UTF-16 LE") as myfile:
data=myfile.read()

print(data)
# parse file
obj = json.loads(data)
```